# How to get the properties of a class using reflection (specifying how many levels of hierarchy) in C#.Net?

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection, properties

So for example:

```
class GrandParent {
    public int GrandProperty1 { get; set; }
    public int GrandProperty2 { get; set; }
}

class Parent : GrandParent {
    public int ParentProperty1 { get; set; }
    public int ParentProperty2 { get; set; }
    protected int ParentPropertyProtected1 { get; set; }
}

class Child : Parent {
    public int ChildProperty1 { get; set; }
    public int ChildProperty2 { get; set; }
    protected int ChildPropertyProtected1 { get; set; }
}
```

but when i do this:

```
public String GetProperties() {
    String result = "";
    Child child = new Child();
    Type type = child.GetType();
    PropertyInfo[] pi = type.GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in pi) {
        result += prop.Name + "\n";
    }
    return result;
}
```

the function returns

`ChildProperty1` 
`ChildProperty2` 
`ParentProperty1` 
`ParentProperty2` 
`GrandProperty1` 
`GrandProperty2`

but I just need the properties up to the Parent class

`ChildProperty1` 
`ChildProperty2` 
`ParentProperty1` 
`ParentProperty2`

Is there any possible way which we could specify how many levels of hierarchy could be used so the result returned would be as desired? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not out of the box. You could write something custom to do it though.

Comment: Don't use string concatenation in a loop.

Comment: @Dmitriy Matveev: This is just to test the results. =)

Comment: Now, I've got another problem... If I wont do string concatenation, then I might need to add the items to a generic list... I'll try to solve this later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly` with `Type.GetProperties` to search only the properties declared on the Type and exclude properties that were inherited. Then you can write a method that gets the properties of a type and recursively its parent types for a specified recursion depth.

```
string GetProperties(Type type, int depth)
{
    if (type != null && depth > 0)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        PropertyInfo[] pi = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
            BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in pi)
        {
            result += prop.Name + "\n";
        }
        result += GetProperties(type.BaseType, depth - 1) + "\n";
        return result;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Example:

```
Console.WriteLine(GetProperties(typeof(Child), 2));
```

Output:

```
ChildProperty1
ChildProperty2
ParentProperty1
ParentProperty2
```

Comment: i have tried that but to no avail...
Thanks for the response. I appreciate it! =)

Comment: You need to specify e.g. `BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance` in addition to `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly`.

Comment: If I only have a string with full class name, and property name like MyNameSpace1.X.Y.Z.ClassName, and PropertyName ?

Answer (score 4):

No.

```
if (prop.DeclaringType == typeof(Child) || 
prop.DeclaringType == typeof(Child).BaseType)
```

Add the above line, before `result += prop.Name + "\n";`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but something like the following should do the trick.

```
IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetProperties(Type t, int depth)
{
  List<PropertyInfo> properties = new List<PropertyInfo>();
  if (type != null)
  {
    while (depth-- > 0)
    {
      properties.AddRange(type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance) ;
      type = type.BaseType;
    }
  }
  return properties;
}
```

Comment: Nice. I think you'll need change `type` somewhere in the loop though.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I've added the "type=type.BaseType;" line, which should solve the problem.